# Как правильно реализовать очистку таблицы?

Tags: java, swing, таблицы

Есть таблица, объект класса `JTable` и ее модель `DefaultTableModel`. Пытаюсь реализовать полную очистку таблицы по нажатию на кнопку. Никаких методов модели не переопределял, пользуюсь стандартными. Пробую так:

```
clearDataButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i=0; i < dataTableModel.getRowCount(); i++) dataTableModel.removeRow(i);
        }
    });
```

Здесь в цикле, я прохожу по всем строкам таблицы, и удаляю их. Вроде бы все должно работать, но допустим, у меня есть таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Одинаковыми данными заполнил для примера. Вот что происходит по нажатии на кнопку очистки таблицы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Почему в таблице остаются строки? Как правильно реализовать полную очистку таблицы?

Comment: можно так: `setModel(new DefaultTableModel());`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Так потом перестают работать кнопки добавить точку и удалить точку. А также убираются заголовки столбцов.

Comment: Не работают кнопки - наверное потому что Вы сослались на модель при создании кнопки, вместо получения модели в момент нажатия

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Попробовал получить модель в момент нажатия, все равно ломаются кнопки. Пробовал так: DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)dataTable.getModel();

Ну действие над моделью

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Мой цикл тоже должен работать по идее. Мне интересно, где я ошибся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Нужно использовать метод `setRowCount(0);` для очистки строк таблицы.

```
clearDataButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)dataTable.getModel();
            model.setRowCount(0);

        }
    });
```

Но мне все еще не понятно, почему не работает цикл.